# How to unmarshal a named type alias from a document with mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a struct with updated_at field which I want to be JSON encoded as a unix timestamp.

I tried the following which doesn’t seem to work,
the updated_at field is never unmarshalled from the MongoDB document:

```
type Timestamp time.now

func (t Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    ts := time.Time(t).Unix()
    fmt.Println(ts)
    stamp := fmt.Sprint(ts)

    return []byte(stamp), nil
}


type User struct {
    UpdatedAt *Timestamp `bson:"updated_at,omitempty" json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

I found a temp solution, to write the struct’s MarshalJSON function, doing something like this (changing the UpdatedAt type to *time.Time):

```
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    out := make(map[string]interface{})

    if u.UpdatedAt != nil && !u.UpdatedAt.IsZero() {
        out["updated_at"] = u.UpdatedAt.Unix()
    }

    return json.Marshal(out)
}
```

is there a better or more elegant solution for doing this?

Comment: You mention difficulty in un-marshalling but have not given your UnmarshalJSON() function. Doesn't this (http://play.golang.org/p/9UlXFkC1t-) work?
I don't know mgo or MongoDB. I feel like i'm stating the obvious that for whatever reason is not working with mgo.

Comment: @Gnani I'm talking about unmarshaling from BSON and not from JSON... the field isn't read from the MongoDB document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution elsewhere and wrote a post about it - https://medium.com/coding-and-deploying-in-the-cloud/time-stamps-in-golang-abcaf581b72f

for handling mgo's marshaling/unmarshaling one has to implement the GetBSON() and SetBSON() functions.

Answer (score -1):

Your code isn't working because you need to implement `MarshalJSON` on `*Timestamp` not `Timestamp`.

```
func (t *Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) { .... }
```

Comment: @GalBen-Haim your question wasn't clear and your added code example was for json.

Comment: using Timestamp pointer instead of value won't work. it wastes a lot of time from me.
for MarshalJSON you must not use the pointer.